# How to disable elastic effect in ios devices but i want to allow page scrolling to my web page, is it possible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a website in which **facing elastic effect in ios devices (iPad, iPhone)**. when I have disable elastic effect using jQuery then page become fixed (position). Guide me how can we fix this issue.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sunilrawat/u6qq5aye/#&togetherjs=k58AGB9t2q

Hi Sahil Dhir,
                    I am sharing jsfiddle path.

Comment: You dint share the jquery code that is making some elastic effect and what is your elastic effect is not clear in the fiddle.. Please share full code .

Comment: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/eb/1e/3d/eb1e3dc9b24728f4c51d959f9961a930.jpg
 i am sharing an image the white blank area in bottom appear in iPad and iPhone when drag the screen and i have not added any js yet on dummy html.